# How to use String Replace in NSIS

Tags: maven, nsis

I use maven, I have a maven-project with version X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT, and I use [maven-nsis-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/). Because the Version is in format X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT, I have to remove this suffix and repace it with a 0.

The maven plugin [maven-nsis-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/) generates a project.nsh:

```
!define PROJECT_VERSION "4.23.9-SNAPSHOT"
```

which is used in my setup.nsi:

```
!include target\project.nsh

Section VersionReplace
    Push "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
    Push "-SNAPSHOT"
    Push "0"
    Call StrRep
    Pop $0

    !define VERSION_SHORT $0
SectionEnd

Name "Installer ${VERSION_SHORT}"

(...)

VIProductVersion ${VERSION_SHORT}
```

**Problem**: In the Console i can see:

```
Name: "Installer $0"
(...)
VIAddVersionKey: "ProductVersion" "$0"
```

so the $0 is not replaced. **What am I doing wrong?**

Replacement function used: [StrRep](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrRep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the [!searchreplace](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.4.14) command, which runs at compile time

```
!searchreplace PROJECT_VERSION_SHORT ${PROJECT_VERSION} "-SNAPSHOT" ".0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` and `VIProductVersion` are installer attributes that are taken into account at compile time while creating the .exe

The `StrRep` function will be called at runtime when passing into the section `VersionReplace`, and it will be too late to change `Name` or `VIProductVersion`.

BTW: if you want to define some value at runtime like in your `!define VERSION_SHORT $0` statement, create a variable with the `Var` statement and modify the variable (with `StrCpy`). A `!define` is a string replacement defined during compilation that cannot change. What you have actually written is that `VERSION_SHORT` is an alias for `$0`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that sections are executed at runtime. Then I found the information in the Docs. See other answer.